# How so slice tuple inside of list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

so i got this tuple inside a list.

```
myList = [("david", 35, 200000), ("Gina", 15, 500), ("james", 43, 152), ("lenny", 24, 10000)]
```

and i wanna print the last index of each tuple (e.g 200000, 500,152,10000).

i tried to do this, but it doesn't work

```
myList = [("david", 35, 200000), ("Gina", 15, 500), ("james", 43, 152), ("lenny", 24, 10000)]
x = myList[:][2]
print(x)
```

and also i tried to do this, but still doesn't work.

```
myList = [("david", 35, 200000), ("Gina", 15, 500), ("james", 43, 152), ("lenny", 24, 10000)]
x = 0
for x in myList:
  print(myList[x][2])
x+=1
```

Does anyone know how to print all of the second index of each tupple inside a list?

Comment: @Chris: how about you add it as an answer?

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To get the second index of each tuple.

```
myList = [("david", 35, 200000), ("Gina", 15, 500), ("james", 43, 152), ("lenny", 24, 10000)]

for i in myList:
    print(i[2])
```

If you want to print the last item of each tuple, then do

> `print(i[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
x = myList[:][2]
print(x)
```

you are essentially returning the third element of this list. `myList[:]` returns the original list and hence the expression returns the third element of this list.

What you need to do is to iterate over the entire list and access each element (which returns the tuples in the list). Then you can access the last element of each tuple:

```
for el in myList:
    print(el[2])
```